# How does stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(_:) return nil?

Tags: ios, swift

> ***UIWebView Class Reference***:
>
> **Swift**
>   `func stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(_ script: String) -> String?`
>
> **Return Value**
>   The result of running the JavaScript script passed in the script parameter, or nil if the script fails.

If I give the function a garbled string of random text, for example:

```
    let x = viewController.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(
        "aadfasdjfdsl.sdfsadsf.asdfasd[0]"
    )
    print("-->\(x)<--")
```

it does not return nil--it returns:

```
Optional("")
```

How can it return nil?

Comment: May be the function call is wrong? so it is not reaching actual output, try put an alert, see if it works.

Comment: *"Although this method is not deprecated, best practice is to use the `evaluateJavaScript:completionHandler:` method of the `WKWebView` class instead."*  Have you tried this?

Comment: @jtbandes: No, because I'm using the `UIWebView class` which does not implement that method.

Comment: print(x), what do you get now ?